# How to use linear-gradient to column chart in highchart.js

Tags: highcharts

[image]

i want to add linear gradient to series in hightchats column chart.
check above image.

please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: img]

Check [Linear gradients](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors)  and apply with the required colors in series.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0.3,

      shadow: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#f79685'],
        [1, '#f45c42']
      ]
    }

  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4],
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#f699ff'],
        [1, '#d71ee8']
      ]
    }

  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kn1y2rx/1/) demo